# htaccess - Redirect image requests to single file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to configure **.htaccess** to redirect 404 requests for images to single file: **404.jpg**
This is my code:

```
# If there's no file at the requested path..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Then, if it's an image file, try the other image:
RewriteRule /([^/]*\.(gif|png|jpg|svg|JPG|PNG|JPEG|jpeg))$ https://example.com/images/404.jpg
```

This works for fine:

```
http://example.com/upload/images/a/ac/UserAvatar.png
```

But it's not working for:

```
http://example.com/upload/images/thumb/a/ac/UserAvatar.png/100px-UserAvatar.png
```

Any solutions? Cheers

Comment: Are you sure you have the folder `/UserAvatar.png/`? Then I would suggest to rename it to just `UserAvatar`.

Comment: I'm working on the backup files from cache. In short, I have 5000+ *.html files linking to images which are non-existing. I can't edit this *.html files or create directories as it will takes months to finish. The best solution for me would be to redirect all image requests to single image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|png|jpg|svg|jpeg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/images/404.jpg [L]
```

Check if you have mod_rewrite enabled

```
apachectl -M | grep rewrite
```

and AllowOverride activated

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Good luck!